# Is it possible to have inheritance in your generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to abstract away some functionality whilst keeping the types generic. Check the code below

```
public interface IDataItem{}
public class DataItemImpl : IDataItem{}
```

So that is my interface and implementation. Then here is the service interface, the abstraction and the specific implementation

```
public interface IDataMapper<T> where T : IDataItem{}
public abstract class AbstractDataMapper<T> : IDataMapper<T> where T : IDataItem
public class CustomDataMapper : AbstractDataMapper<DataItemImpl>, IDataMapper<DataItemImpl>
```

As you can see my concrete implementation declares the generic type to be `DataItemImpl` which I would assume to be correct as it implements `IDataItem` and thus satisfies the contraint of `T`

The problem I am having is that when I try and assign the concrete implementation to the generic interface like this :

```
IDataMapper<IDataItem> mapper = new CustomDataMapper();
```

I get a big fat error saying :

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'CustomDataMapper'` to `'IDataMapper<IDataItem>'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

If I cast it explicity the compiler stops moaning, but this smells bad? Is this even possible or is my ambition exceeding my ability at this point?

Comment: `IDataMapper<DataItemImpl> mapper = new CustomDataMapper();` would work.

Comment: Inheritance is the wrong term. What applies here are Co- and Contravariance. Two things that apply to generics and are intentionally designed to mostly work like Inheritance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Comment: As for the error message, note the types. Convert type 'CustomDataMapper' to 'IDataMapper'. **Not** ''CustomDataMapper' to 'IDataMapper<DataItemImpl>'. My guess is that you for some reason I can not understand implemented 'IDataMapper<DataItemImpl>' in CustomDataMapper. This might mess up conversion.

Comment: I think you shoukd make `IDataMapper` covariant: `interface IDataMapper<out T>`.

Comment: If you define the generic type as co-variant that will work `IDataMapper<out T>` however that's only allowed if `T` only comes out of the interface as the return of a method or the type of a read only property.  It cannot be the argument to a method or the type of a writable property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only because two classes have an inheritance-relation does not make any generic class or interface that uses the former ones for their generic arguments have the same relation. In other words:

```
class Derived : Base { }
```

does not imply a relationship between `IMyInterface<Derived>` and `IMyInterface<Base>`. Why? Well, imagine the often quoted example of a `List<Animal>`. Of course both `Lion` and `Giraffe` are implementations of the base-class `Animal`. If we were now able to simply cast a `List<Giraffe>` to `List<Animal>`, you could put a `Lion` into the list:

```
List<Animal> baseList = new List<Giraffe> { ... };
baseList.Add(new Lion()); // rrroaaaaaaaaaa
```

An interface on the other hand enables co-variance by adding the `out`-keyword to your generic argument.

So in your case you need the `IDataMapper`-interface to be covariant:

```
public interface IDataMapper<out T> where T : IDataItem{}
```

This means the following as [of MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/index):

> An object that is instantiated with a more derived type argument is
>   assigned to an object instantiated with a less derived type argument.
>   Assignment compatibility is preserved.

Answer (score 3):

First

```
public class CustomDataMapper : AbstractDataMapper<DataItemImpl> //, IDataMapper<DataItemImpl>
```

is sufficient since `AbstractDataMapper<DataItemImpl>` brings with it the requirement that `IDataMapper<DataItemImpl>` be implemented.

Next, you will notice that the cast requirement falls away if you do this

```
IDataMapper<DataItemImpl> mapper = new CustomDataMapper();
```

The difference is that `CustomDataMapper` IS-A `AbstractDataMapper<DataItemImpl>` which *directly* IS-A `IDataMapper<DataItemImpl>`.

`IDataMapper<DataItemImpl>` IS-NOT-(necessarily the only) `IDataMapper<IDataItem>` since a class other than `DataItemImpl` could come along later and also implement `IDataItem`.

Comment: However if the generic type can be defined as co-variant that cast will work like you can cast a `List<string>` to a `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: "Hence the need to be explicit with a cast." - which will simply fail... Not exactly sure why you added that line to otherwise good answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Right you are; trigger happy, didn't think it through.  Thanks.